# How exactly does "importing a wallet" work?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, ether, import, backup

I think I might import my old wallet using Geth but there's something that's not clear.

I have made a wallet backup a few months ago. However I've earned some ETH after that backup.

If I restore this old backup, will I get the ETH that I've earned after I've made my backup ? Or is a backup more like a system backup where you just get your wallet back the way it was ?

PS : My backup filename starts with "UTC--year-month-day". Is this the right file to import ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by "I've earned some ETH after that backup"? That you have received some ether in your account since the last time you backed it up?

If so then yes, you will have that ether. The *UTC--year-month-day* file is called a keystore and contains the private key of your ethereum account, which you could think of kind of like the password to your account. With this any ether that you received in the past and any more that you receive will be accessible.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I wanted to know :)

Comment: No worries, happy to help :)